# array Adapter Constructor

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter

I need to make my `adapter` display images so i made an array of integers and put in it an id of images, but when i sent it to the array adapter constructor it get me an error because The type `Integer`. How could i solve this problem?

the error appear Here **super(context,resource, objects);**

**My GridViewAdapter class**:

```
package com.example.hima.moviesapp;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import java.util.ArrayList;


/**
* Created by Hima on 3/23/2016.
 */
public class GridViewAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
   private Context mContext;
   private int layoutResourceId;
   private ArrayList<Integer > mGridImages = new ArrayList<Integer>();
 public GridViewAdapter(Context context, int resource, ArrayList<Integer> objects) {
     //the error apear here!!
     super(context,resource, objects);
     this.mContext=context;
     this.layoutResourceId=resource;
     this.mGridImages=objects;
 }

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View row = convertView;
    ImageView image;
    if(row == null){
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) mContext).getLayoutInflater();
        row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);
        image= (ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.movieImage);
        row.setTag(image);
    }
    else{
        image = (ImageView)row.getTag();
    }
    int temp = mGridImages.get(position);
    image.setImageResource(temp);
    return row;
}
}
```

**MyMainFragment class**:

```
package com.example.hima.moviesapp;

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.GridView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
  public class GridViewFragment extends Fragment {
  int[] DummyImages = {R.drawable.first,R.drawable.second,R.drawable.third,R.drawable.fourth,
                    R.drawable.fifth,R.drawable.sixth};
public GridViewFragment() {
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

  View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
    ArrayList<Integer>DummyPosters= new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i=0;i<DummyImages.length;i++) {
        DummyPosters.add(DummyImages[i]);
    }
    GridView gridView = (GridView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.gridView);
    gridView.setAdapter(new GridViewAdapter(getActivity(),R.id.movieImage,DummyPosters));

    return rootView;
}
}
```

Comment: Change type of ArrayAdapter<String> to ArrayAdapter<Integer>

Answer (score 1):

Your adapter is expecting array of Strings, that's why it crashes. 
It does so because you pass String as a generic type in your adapter

`public class GridViewAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>`

To fix that change your adapter to extend `ArrayAdapter<Integer>`

Answer (score 1):

Try to change

```
public class GridViewAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
```

to

```
public class GridViewAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Integer> {
```